# Is there a way to log the username of a failed Oracle login in Java?

Tags: java, oracle, spring-mvc, tomcat, error-handling

We have a number of development environments and an application that opens 20+ logins to our database in each environment.

Every time someone misconfigures an application, we get a log entry that says simply:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

This happens a lot, and it would simplify life tremendously if either Spring Framework, Oracle or Apache Tomcat could be configured to report the **username** that could not log in.

This usually happens during application startup when Spring is wiring the beans for the application, so I'm not sure if our code (e.g., custom error pages) is even available yet.

Anyone have any cool ideas about how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the database level, you can enable **AUDIT TRAIL** to log all the login details. It could be done by setting the `audit_trail` parameter to true.

```
show parameter audit_trail
```

Once enabled for unsuccessful logons, all failed logon attempts will be directed to the database audit trail `SYS.AUD$` table. You could query `dba_audit_trail` to fetch the details:

```
select 
   os_username,
   username,
   terminal,
   to_char(timestamp,'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
from
   dba_audit_trail;
```

Comment: That's probably what we'll have to do.   Given that all the initialization on the application side happens inside Spring and Tomcat code, we would have to (ugh) fork that code to to do this logging.   Don't want to do that.    Thank you for the information!